# Proving a function is nonlinear

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

In $\mathbb{R}^{1}$, we can prove a function is nonlinear by showing $f(ax + by) \neq a\cdot f(x) + b\cdot f(y).$

What about $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? In particular, I want to show $F(x, y) = (-y, e^{x})$ is nonlinear. How can I do this? What about for $F(x, y, z)$?

Comment: linear $F(x,y)=(ax+by,cx+dy)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's $f(a {\bf x} + b {\bf y}) \ne a f({\bf x}) + b f({\bf y})$, where $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ are vectors.  In your example, you could take ${\bf x} = (1,0)$, ${\bf y} = (0,0)$, so 
$a {\bf x} + b {\bf y} = (a, 0)$, and $f(a,0) = (0, e^a) \ne a (0,1) = a f(1,0)$.

Comment: Ok, this answers my question. Thanks